# Why were those colors chosen to be the default palette for 256-color VGA?

Tags: ibm-pc, vga

Although subjective, I believe I'm not the only one considering default VGA 256 color palette to be hideous and ugly.

What is the story behind this, why were these particular colors chosen?

Comment: some colors are for compatibility with older gfx like EGA,CGA and the rest is a compromise between usually needed colors for Apps at that time and [color dithering purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36820654/2521214) so you can have "hi" quality images on the same palette to ease up the apps speed ... for really high quality image output you need combine [quantization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214) and dithering... so n the end is not about how ugly the palette looks but how usable it is

Comment: @Spektre I would say the default colour palette is not usable for the purpose you mention. Do you know any apps that used the default set of 256 colors? A more usable default palette for what you describe would  a 6x6x6 set of RGB triplets for quite coarse gradients but covers 100% of available RGB gamut.

Comment: images (pixel art or even pictures) definitely looked good, so like they say in the answers, it must be about the way you look at the palette

Comment: @golimar: The question is about the _default_ VGA palette though. Most developers and artists at the time did indeed consider the default inappropriate for their needs and used customized palettes instead. I'd go so far as to say that it was the fact that you could customize the palette that made it possible to create good-looking images on VGA cards in the first place.

Comment: @golimar That's because nobody used the **default** palette but a **custom** palette, and this is question is about the BIOS default.

Comment: @Justme what you described will be (256-16)/7 = ~34 color steps per each RGB combination which would be really better for just dithering in RGB space than what we got but what we got are HSV based color steps instead which much better coincides with human vision so even if mathematicaly RGB distance to dithered colors is bigger it should be less in HSV so visulay more closer ... Its hard to say which app uses default and which custom palette without peeking but to my knowledge majority of pixel art based stuff was custom palette.

Comment: It might be helpful to include an image or link [to what the palette *is*](https://www.fountainware.com/EXPL/vga_color_palettes.htm).

Comment: @Spektre: For any kind of normal photographic content, having three luminance levels between black and white would be far too few, and having 24 hues would be excessive.  Cutting the number of hues from 24 to 16 or 12 would allow a much more useful variety of hues and saturation levels.

Comment: @Spektre "HSV [...] much better coincides with human vision". HSV is very far from any understanding of human perception of color. Our eyes have sensors sensitive to blue, green and red (well, reddish green and greenish red really), and those signals are converted to a luminosity, a red-green balance, and a blue-yellow balance before they leave the eyes. Nowhere is there a physical representation of hue or saturation involved in our vision.

Comment: @CrisLuengo HSV and CIE are closely tight to averaged human color vision (perception of color on averaged human sample group so eclidean distance is "equal" to human perception of color difference) you are exchanging RGB with [XYZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e51Ko.png) that is oversimplification as our color perception is not that simple as the bands are overlapping along with "red" having two peaks. Yes I agree we do not have hue nor saturation but the link with human vision is that distance between colors in HSV and CIE is linear to human color difference perception ...

Comment: @Spektre H in HSV is defined as an angle where red, green and blue are arbitrarily put at 120 degrees from each other, and V is a linear combination of RGB. Distances in HSV are **very** far from linearly related to perceptual distances, even further than RGB. I mean, how do you even measure a distance when one of the axes is an angle? HSV never intended to mimic perceptual distances, it was designed as an easy way to specify colors in a GUI.

Comment: @Spektre CIE XYZ is an affine transformation of (linear) RGB, not meant to be perceptually uniform in any way, but the transformation makes the color representation somewhat more related to human perception. CIE Lab is one approximation to perceptual uniformity, CIE Luv is another. Neither are actually perceptually uniform, but at least they transform the intensity (Y from XYZ) into something that matches our perception of intensities (a non-linear mapping, which HSV doesn't do), and distances there attempt to mimic perceptual distances.

Comment: Just a hunch, but HSV is also one of a few colour spaces that lends itself towards Bayer dithering.

Comment: @Spektre A highly respected video engineer Charles Poynton has stated in his Colour FAQ that usual formulations of HSB/HLS are flawed with respect to properties of color vision.

Answer (score 92):

### TL;DR: It's All About How To Look At the Palette

[image: 256-color VGA palette]

That way it doesn't look any hideous and ugly, or does it?

---

### How Come?

> What is the origin of the default 256-color VGA palette?

IBM's BIOS code :))

SCNR. I guess you ask more about the reasoning for it's content and ordering, right? In that case it's about packing as much functionality as possible into a single palette.

> Although subjective, I believe I'm not the only one considering default VGA 256 color palette to be hideous and ugly.

Not so sure, it's pretty clean and made to support several items:

- Providing compatibility with 16 colour modes (*1)
- Providing a simple gray scale mode
- Providing a rich colour field that is

  - fit for photo like pictures
  - allowing simple picture manipulation
  - allowing forms of animation
- Providing (a few) user defined colours not touched by BIOS.

> What is the story behind this, why were these particular colors chosen?

IBM describes it on p. 4-39 of the technical reference as

[image: The internal palette of the video subsystem is not used to select colors. It is set by BIOS and should not be changed. The external palette in the video DAC is programmed by the BIOS such that the first 16 locations contain colors that are compatible with colors of other modes. See Figure 4-27 on page 4-40. The second 16 registers contain 16 evenly spaced gray shades. The remaining 216 locations are loaded based on a hue-saturation-intensity model tuned to provide a usable, generic color set that covers a wide range of color values.]

This fulfils all 4 requirements:

- The first 16 colours are encoded exactly as with all 16 colour modes (0Dh/0Eh/10h/12h) which in turn use the same 4 bit encoding as the colour attributes of all text modes (*1).
- The next 16 deliver an even lit 4 bit black (10h) to white (1Fh) grayscale
- The remaining code space is used to deliver an evenly spaced, [HSV colour cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#/media/File:HSV_color_solid_cylinder_saturation_gray.png) (*2) based on a

  - 24 **[hue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue)** [**RGB** wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_wheel#/media/File:RGB_color_wheel.svg), starting at blue, with 8 subdivisions per R,G and B, resulting in 24 (3x8) discrete "hues". Each of those is present in
  - 3 level of **[saturation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness#Saturation)** (colourfulness) and further in
  - 3 level of **intensity**(value of [brightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brightness))

  Those 216 (3x8x3x3) colours, together with the 16 base colours and 16 gray scale (=248) leave 8 unused definitions. By guaranteeing that the BIOS will not touch them those
- 8 colour definitions are guaranteed free for user applications.

Bottom Line: it's all about serving for 4 different needs in a single colour table:

- A colour palette as natural and evenly spaced (*3) as possible

while still offering

- 16 base colours ordered compatible
- binary coded gray scale
- user definable colours

All of this only looks kind of 'weird' when looking at the table without seeing those 4 purposes and the way the full colour table is structured obeying the prime number 3 embedded thrice to please the RGB colour as well as the available code space.

Of course the usual way of displaying the palette as 16x16 entries isn't helpful either(*4):

[image]

*(Picture taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_13h#/media/File:VGA_palette_with_black_borders.svg))*

Reordering it according to the 16 + 16 + 24x3x3 + 8 structure gives a way better impression(*5):

[image]

The four different groups are now clearly visible with the middle part nicely presenting the underlying sequence of

- 24 hues, going from blue to blue around the circle,

  each provided 9 times to offer a product in
- 3 level of saturation (colourfulness) and
- 3 level of brightness

Beside well spread covering of colour space, this 3 by 3 ordering also allows any picture made of those 24 hues can be direct desaturated and/or dimmed by a simple operation:

- Adding 24/48 reduces saturation, while
- Adding 72/144 reduces brightness.

Having this ability allows certain styles of picture manipulation as well as animation, like fase in/out from/to black/white.

---

In conclusion, **I would think that combining all of the above requirements into a single palette is quite an achievement.**

---

*1 - Which in turn were selected for compatibility with the CGA/EGA [8+8 RGB-I mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_Graphics_Adapter#With_an_RGBI_monitor).

*2 - HSV vs. RGB is maybe the most overlooked part when programmers and engineers think or talk about this (and other) palette(s). They start auf from an RGB PoV which describes a technology to create colour by adding three base colours. A quite convenient system from an engineering perspective, as it reduces the problem to 3 values of equal weight. Except, that's not like human vision (or natural colour) works.

It's also not the way picture handling and manipulation works. Tools like Photoshop or Gimp primary handle colour manipulation in HSV categories.

This also touches the issue between image creation and picture handling. Thinking in RGB is fine to do Monkey Island, but not for a photo app. The standard palette tries to please the later as well.

*3 - Please note that uncounted books were written about various colour theories during the last 2000+ years, all in their own right due the complex nature of colour creation and human perception.

RGB as technology driven format does not solve any of that, but rather add another layer of complication (due translation). Of course we can punch ahead and throw enough resources (like a 24+ bit palette) at the problem to seemingly solve. Except, it's not solved, just hidden.

Thus naturally/evenly spaced can not mean numeric equal spacing of RGB values (like 100%, 66% and 33%) as the human perception does not work linear. The selection of RGB values takes that into account by

- 'lifting' *(de)saturation* as 0%, 48% and 71% and
- 'dimming' *brightness* as 100%, 44% and 29%.

Doing so creates complementary levels for a richer colour space than doing either linear would.

*4 - Three being a prime doesn't go well neither with a decimal nor a binary number system, or does it?

*5 - For another image [see here](http://www.thealmightyguru.com/Wiki/index.php?title=Video_Graphics_Array#Colors).

Comment: Even the first block can be divided in two, updated the pics.

Comment: @aybe Thanks for the effort, but that's not the way it is intended. Sure, on CGA it's the RGB+I coding, but that's not the point her - see the cited IBM documentation. Added a footnote for that.

Comment: I see... good catch :)

Comment: The color palette isn't very natural, though. If we were to go about it today, we'd map 216 perceptively equidistant points of the color space... trading granularity in desaturated tones for much finer luma resolution. But that's why most everyone had to use a custom palette.

Comment: Nitpick to *2: Should be "3 being coprime to both 10 and 2 doesn't go well...". 5 is also a prime and goes extremely well with a decimal number system. ;-)

Comment: I wonder what the rationale was for choosing these particular levels of brightness and of saturation for the three bands (approx. 100%, 50%, and 30%, respectively). The last two levels are very close to each other, and as a result, the overall palette has way too many colors that are perceptually indistinguishable. In other words, while the default palette offered perhaps 48 brightly colored hues, it also had ~96 desaturated dark tones that were extremely hard to tell apart.

Comment: Not sure about the "as natural as possible" claim. For what definition of "natural" is that? Seems more like, someone tried to do at least something non-random. Some engineer's best effort.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine And as well the reason why there are many theories of colour. Not to mention that people often mix lumina with saturation, which is not the same.  The standard palette is a good approach for natural looking pictures as it reduces the quantisation issues linear RGB palettes have. Nature (and in revolutionary result he human eye) is way more defined due alternating regions of comparable small changes.

Comment: @Schmuddi I added a footnote for that. The noteworthy parts here are that, in RGB numbers, the bands are complementary as (roughly) 100/50/30 and 0/50/70. this not only more closely features the natural occurrence of small delta within a region but also adds up a more evenly distribution than both going 100/66/33.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica yes, it's a best effort to integrate several requirements with 'natural' pictures being one of them. Human vision is not absolute, but relative with a focus on detecting small differences. That's why having more 'dim' tones will reduce the usual quatization effects of small palettes. You're also right that the non randomness seems intended, as the 3x3 ordering allows manipulation in saturation and  brightness by simple add/sub operations. See the added footnote *2.

Comment: @Raffzahn I wonder if HSV rendering was envisioned. For humans, the dimmest tones are resolved with rods, so color is less important, while pure colors need much more resolution. Most neighbors in the 30% block are indistinguishable, while the gap between 100% and 50% is overly wide, and pure colors are too far apart to depict a smooth rainbow.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine I have a hard time to see any reason to structure it HSV with no intention to use. HSV seems the best way to maximize use of the available code space of 216(224) code points. Note that S/V is complementary, so combined it's more of a 0/30/50/70/100 spacing (might need a(nother) reorder to show up). Yes, colour is just a candy on top of gray scale, but it's not about absolute values but relative to neighbouring values. Try to convert a 24 bit RGB to VGA and 3-3-2. In comparision 3-3-2 won't be any better (maybe even more gradient edges) despite 25% more code points.

Comment: @Raffzahn HSV is the most logical, but the least efficient way to record color. If you look at the color circle, its center basically looks gray. More than half of the HSV color space is wasted on colors too desaturated or too dark to be distinguishable. Even RGB is more efficient. CIELAB (if reduced to visible and reproducible colors) is the most efficient.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine well,one can prefer a certain colour space for various (usually good) reasons. LAB is a very nice and capable model, but not really fit for computing as it needs high resolution as well as spherical calculation. Fitting a somewhat equally spaces LAB in 216 code points will not leave any usable symmetry -and forced into one result in the same issues as HSB. the VGA palette is about real world computing in 8 bit on a 1986 PC, not what's nice with a super computer plug in:)

Comment: I think reducing the number of hues to 16 while varying the number of saturation levels based upon lightness could have allowed a more useful variety of colors for many purposes.  For example, have five lightness values between black and white, with two having two saturation levels, two having three, and one having four, for a total of 14 lightness/saturation combinations.

Comment: @Raffzahn I think your RGB vs HSV footnotes are a bit misleading. Any colour, realizable, non-realizable but imaginable, or non-realizable and non-imaginable can be represented with three variables within a given gamut - so a colour in RGB will be identical in HSV, it just has different "coordinate system" for same colour. Some adjustment operations need to be done in HSV-alike colour space, such as brightness, contrast, saturation and hue you find on a TV before converted to RGB for CRT. Some video operations such as crossfade needs to be done in RGB space. You use what is most suitable.

Comment: @Justme I don't think it's that misleading; they specify RGB as three values _of equal weight_, meaning that RGB is a linear coordinate system in contrast to HSV as a cylindrical coordinate system.

Comment: @Raffzahn Exactly, LAB space is perceptually best, but costly to compute in. In practice, everyone just used RGB and a custom palette. But I wonder if this mini-HSV was originally envisioned for easier computations. Probably not though.

Comment: @Justme HSV being cylindrical results in duplicate colors. For color depth of d, ??0 is d*d-1 redundant blacks, ?0? is d*(d-1) redundant greys. With d=4, that's 28/64 or 44% of the color space wasted right here. The VGA palette has actually cut out some of that waste by trimming S=0 and V=0 in favor of a separate grayscale block. Otherwise it's 4.5*2*2 bit HSV.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine I guess we can agree that RGB doesn't really hold as colour model. It's only good for ray gun control. Any meaningful model will need transformation - and that's what the palette is about - and the basic issue with of limited space. No matter what model is used, that code space will not allow much. ~200 code points allow only a very limited number of factorizations. Further limited by most models having 3 components. 216 is very nice due it gives "2x2x2x3x3x3", allowing with  24x3x3 the largest possible number of 'base' colours while still allowing HSV operations.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine That trimming is part of why VGA is such a good solution. Any plain RGB wastes a lot of space. HSV less, and an 'unevenly' picked HSV, like here, again less.  Of course any cutting reduces resolution, but the way it is done it reduces the effects while still allowing parametric manipulation. It's a best effort in areally limiting situation: only a few code points, no space for complex code and no computing power to use it either.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine Thinking about, it might be nice to visualize the 216 VGA values in LAB space. do you know any tool capable to draw this or maybe an animation?

Comment: @Raffzahn I know of this - https://colorizer.org/ - but no software able to do it in bulk. As for representation efficiency, I'd argue that RGB still packs more unique colors into the space, since any R,G,B combo is a unique color. HSV has duplicates. LAB offers [color manipulation with superior quality](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/64287/what-is-the-difference-between-hsv-and-cie-lab-color-space), but it's much more computationally costly to convert to/from RGB.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine I was more thinking of something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space#/media/File:CIELAB_color_space_front_view.png). LAB and HSV as IMHO useful than RGB. They organize colour the way it's perceived, RGB _wants_ does colour the way technology generates it,having a restricted space and non linear fashion. Linear in perception, not generative technology. And perception is what we want to create and manipulate to get a result. Transformation to please generative technology is what we have computers (here palettes) for.

Comment: @Raffzahn I guess I'd summarize it as: RGB is a hardware engineer's view of color, HSV a programmer's, LAB a visual artist's. Anyway, great answer, and I've asked a followup question, to see if this math was actually used: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28020/were-vga-palettes-math-hacks-used-in-practice

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine HSV would be a hardware engineer's view if you look at color TVs. There's brightness signal for video, and the phase angle of colorburst determines hue, and amplitude of colorburst determines saturation.

Comment: @Justme: Would a hardware engineer view things in terms of amplitude and phase angle, or in terms of in-phase and out-of-phase components?

Comment: Given that 16-color VGA modes mapped through the 64-color EGA palette, I wonder if it would have made sense to make the first 64 colors look like EGA colors?  A substantial variety of nice gradients could have been accommodated if the first 64 colors were mapped like EGA colors with a the four brightness components for each color being (0,21,42,63), the next were similar but with the brightness components being (0,7,56,63), then (0,14,49,63), and (0,21,28,63).  The 24 redundant colors within the last 192 where all components were 0 or 63 could be filled with e.g. additional grayscales.

Comment: @supercat I don't think so, due to software using BIOS and e.g. expecting color indexes like EGA does, e.g. colour 0x0F being white even if it is sent to monitor as 0x3F in 6-bit format. And MCGA lacking EGA compatibility so many EGA games had to support MCGA by just using first 16 colors in 256 color mode. And it is simpler that text attribute color indexes match the first 16 colors. Sure, when VGA card is in EGA mode, it has to use the EGA palette in RAMDAC for displaying the same 64 colors.

Comment: @Schmuddi Look up "Weber's Law" and "just-noticeable difference". Human perception is generally less sensitive as the overall intensity of something increases. It's why volume controls on electronic devices aren't linear. It's why the light from a power led might be bothersome while trying to sleep in a dark room but be completely unnoticeable during the day. It's why switching from a 5lb weight to a 10lb weight at the gym might seem big, but going from a 45lb weight to a 50lb weight seems like nothing.

Comment: @anjama: If BIOS routines mapped specified colors through a translation table whose values would be changed via the EGA's "set palette" routines, that would yield behavior matching the EGA 320x200 mode, at least in situations where programs set palettes before drawing things.  A program that wanted to support EGA and VGA, and draw some screen content in enhanced fashion on VGA, but use the same code for parts of the screen that should use EGA colors, could work smoothly with such a design if there were a separate "plot with VGA color" routine.

Comment: @anjama well said. Didn't know it's called Weber's Law. Thanks for that pointer.

Answer (score 25):

The VGA default palette in the 256 colour mode (Mode 13h) first has 16 color entries from CGA (which is also same as default 16-color EGA palette and the only palette for 320x200 EGA mode)

Next 16 color entries are 16 shades of gray.

And the next 216 color entries has been already mentioned; they are sets of 24 hues, in 3 different saturation values, and in 3 different brightness values. 24 × 3 × 3 = 216.

The final 8 colour entries are black, or maybe left undefined so BIOS does not overwrite them when changing modes.

After doing some further research, about the time when VGA was being designed, real graphics workstations already had better color capabilities and HSV was a bit of a craze because it provides an intuitive color model of picking colors to draw, especially to a non-technical or artist type of person using the computer. In reality HSV is quite unuseful for any other task than colour picking, as said by even highly appreciated video engineer Charles Poynton, while specifically mentioning HSV/HSL being flawed with respect to the properties of color vision.

So my guess is, because HSV was all the craze in colour picking back then, and it is a nice feature to at least initialize the palette by default to some colors instead of filling it with black or left uninitialized, the VGA default palette simply was initialized with something somebody came up, with 24 hues in 3 brightness and in 3 saturation combos to draw pretty rainbows and show off the video capabilities compared to EGA for example.

As there is a lot of repetition at different brightness and saturation levels, a part of the palette can be stored in small array and the different brightness and saturation levels could be calculated, as on VGA ROM there is not much free space left for complex palettes after storing all the necessary code and fonts.

Comment: Back in the day, I noticed that the last few colors were inconsistent.  Maybe they would have been reliably left undisturbed if one ran a program to set them before using an application that didn't, but I wouldn't be at all surprised if some VGA card BIOS routines would clear them on a mode change.

Answer (score 4):

If I recall, it's the 16-color default palette, followed by 216 colors chosen as the combinations of 3 luminance values, 3 saturation values, and 24 hue values.  Having 24 hues for all nine combinations of luminance and saturation seems wasteful, but I think the design objective was to allow pretty rainbows at any lightness/saturation combo.

Comment: I think I forgot some 16-level brightness gradients in gray and RGB, but even with those not all 256 entries were used.

Comment: @Supercat, I believe you are misremembering. What you seem to be describing is an HSB (HSV, whatever) color mapping.  As far as I know, VGA only supported direct RGB mapping.

Comment: @RichF: The default palette entries were chosen to contain the RGB values corresponding to 216 HSV triplets.

Comment: I missed that he was referring to 8-bit VGA, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

People may think of VGA as ugly now, but considering what came before it, it offered much more flexibility than most previous home computer color implementations. Those often offered 8 or 16 colors maximum.  When they offered more than that, RAM and memory access time was so expensive that manufacturers reduced screen resolution; 320x200 was a common limit if a computer offered many colors (above 16 and less than or equal to 256 colors total).

That said, original, pure VGA was quite restrictive. (I'm writing about 16-bit VGA, not its backward compatible modes.) Six bits per color component allows for 262,144 total colors. That is far less than healthy human eyes can see. While far in excess of the 256 colors allowed in the GIF image standard, GIF (and 8-bit PNG) has a secret advantage. An image had associated Look Up Tables (LUTs), allowing a given image to access one set of 256 colors from a full 24-bit palette With decent post-processing, a 24-bit image can usually be color-sampled to achieve an "ideal" set of colors for that image. On the other hand, even if a VGA card was advanced enough to offer an 8-bit mapping of each color component, routine software would not (and probably could not with the CPU usually being busy with other stuff than ideal color display) map the 262,144 colors to use the ideal color set from 24-bit digital-to-analog computers.

But from my perspective as someone who lived through evolving home graphics capabilities from the start, VGA was pretty darn good.

For reference, see [List of 16-bit computer color palettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_16-bit_computer_color_palettes)

Comment: I think OP is asking about the *default* mode13h palette, i.e. the one with all the rainbows at different intensities.

Comment: I think ths answer fails to answer the question, it talks about something else. Yes, VGA has 8-bit pixels and 18-bit color lookup table in the RAMDAC, but why the default palette is what it is?

Comment: @Justme, I misread the question, somehow not realizing that it was limited to a small portion of VGA capabilities.