# Were VGA palette's HSV math properties used in practice?

Tags: ibm-pc, video, gaming, vga, color-display

In ["Why were those colors chosen to be the default palette for 256-color VGA?"](https://%20https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27994/what-is-the-origin-of-the-default-256-color-vga-palette), we've established that 216 of its colors represent a 24x3x3 truncated HSV color space.

This results in an inconsistent perceptual distance, so custom palettes were prevalent in commercial apps. However, one answer points out that VGA default palette's HSV allows for some cheap computations: desaturating or dimming colors by [simply adding 24 or 72](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27999/14449).

Was that feature used in any practical application?

I'm interested in finding if any video game, engine, graphics software, middleware, or any other commercial or open-source application (more than a personal training project), performed any effects by doing math with color numbers in the palette. It would be most interesting to see it done with the default VGA palette.

As a second choice, any applications that performed effects through shifting color # in a custom palette that similarly represented a color model. As opposed to doing it in RGB and mapping to the palette, or using preset sprites, or changing the palette itself.

Comment: Dimming or brightening was usually achieved by changing the palette instead of changing the pixel values (because changing the palette is a lot faster), so may guess would be: no, adding/subtracting 24 or 72 was not used in practice.

Comment: I honestly doubt the HSV-ness of default palette was ever used for any purpose by any serious program. However since anyone can write a program that does utilize the HSV-ness of the default palette, such a program likely exists too. Do you specifically mean only the default palette, or any custom palette with similar properties on which similar tricks can be used?

Comment: @Justme Perhaps any custom palette with similar properties would count as "close enough". I've clarified to limit it to notable applications, i.e. anything above a school project.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine Do demos and intros count? I am positive they have used every known trick in the books and even beyond that. It is not a difficult concept of choosing the palette so that you can have different saturation and luminance values for a range of hues, so by adding some offsets you can dim/bright a blob on screen for example.

Comment: @Justme Personally I'd consider that a non-serious use, but a particular example would definitely be better than nothing and show at least someone found a use for this math hack.

Comment: Can you clarify whether or not you're asking about the default VGA palette specifically, or if your question includes custom 256 colour palettes where user-defined mathematical relationships between colour groups hold?

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine Wording like 'math hack' when it's about a feature do sound biased, don't they?

Comment: @Raffzahn I'm using "hack" in a positive sense, as a clever way to do things faster. But let's call it math properties. I didn't want to create an even longer discussion around your answer, and decided a separate question is better to see if it was a *useful* feature.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine If it was used in a demo or intro chances are high it is used in some game too, as many groups also coded games and included effects.  Especially the brightening/dimming part seems plausible to have light and shadow effects, for example the shadow of a ”sprite” on the background.

Comment: @dirkt If we talk about brigthening/dimming the whole image/screen then yes, but not when having objects cast shadow on a background.

Comment: Do you mean the BIOS default palette? Yes or no.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Ideally an example with the default palette, but one with a custom palette would suffice as well.

Comment: If custom palettes are included, then the question is, has anyone ever organized at least a part of a color palette so that math operations on color index numbers have a sensible meaning. And the answer is of course yes. If you place grays in order from darkest to brightest and not randomly, then increasing the color index increases brightness. I'm pretty sure someone has arranged their grays non-randomly at least once.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica is right. Altering pixel data with an offset to achieve an useful result is useful itself, such as drawing the same sprite for more players with offset in pixel data to have different colours for different players. It is of course possible with the default palette too, if you want to work with it - it's just likely so unuseful you really don't want to use the default palette. The question did ask if any serious game or productivity program used the default palette, but we can ask if it ever was a serious program if it uses the default palette. Serious means custom CLUT.

Comment: @Justme Let's low the threshold to any application created for any utilitarian purpose, basically anything more than learning, practicing or experimenting with a programming language.

Comment: @Therac-StandwithPalestine No prob. Also I agree about opening another as it allows direct answers. The point about 'hack' was that a hack is a use of a property in an unintended/not obvious way, but here the use to manipulate HSV as distinct properties seems rather intended and obvious.

Comment: @Raffzahn I'd give it credit for non-obvious, at least, because the color space doesn't map straight to bits, like [some of these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_16-bit_computer_color_palettes), but is a part of a mixed-paradigm palette. Was it a common use? That's the question )) If it was common, someone might find a piece of software (given how much code has been leaked, studies, or released) that used it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's the same palette, but XCom/UFO used a palette composed of the same colors at different brightnesses so that it could do dynamic lighting with it.  I think this may have been a pretty common technique since I think Quake did something similar much later, being designed for a fixed 256-color palette.

Comment: Now, Quake is interesting... Being a 3D game, I recall not even realizing it was in 256 colors. Would be great to look into what exactly it did.

Comment: Actually, Quake does not count for sure. Given Quake being such an advanced game; it did not use a specially arranged palette to do the trick directly, but a separate look-up table for mapping the required colour&brightness value into the fixed 256-color palette, which means, the 256 colors of the VGA could in theory be in any order because it does not matter how the look-up points to them as long as it works. The look-up table was about 16k entries in length to allow for 64 shades for each of the about 256 source colors.

Comment: So Quake used a sort of double-palette system?  Because the original software renderer definitely ran in 256 colors unless you improved the settings with winquake or similar.

Comment: @davolfman No, Quake used a single fixed palette of 256 colors (if you don't count the effect of being hit etc). When you needed to draw a source pixel of original texture (0..255) with amount of light (0..63) applied to it, there is a look-up-table that can map those two values into to one of the 256 VGA colour indexes to write a pixel to video RAM.

Answer (score 3):

I would believe the question is not really answerable the way it is.

For one,the default palette is a manufacturer side offering, as such intended for low effort application, the ones that do not take the extra step to create an application specific one - or an optimized one for each picture.

Any  product of reasonable size or task to make sales worthwhile would have, at DOS times, done its own palettes. This is especially true for demos which usually would use the ability to program the palette for effect. A possible exception could be some build to comply with extreme limitations, like boot sector demos/games.

It doesn't work asking for a use of a certain feature but excluding the class of applications that might use them. Adding statements like 'gap between bright and dim' does not really support the search.

---

Comment: I wouldn't say _any_ demo. There are sometimes (very) size restricted competitions.  Like boot sector games or demos.

Comment: @BlackJack Good point. I should have added that as possibleexception.

Comment: It's not possible to prove a negative. But any one example of any application using this technique would be a positive answer.